# Crawlspider SgmlLinkExtractor allow parameter

Tags: regex, scrapy

The allow parameter in the SgmlLinkExtractor method accepts a regex string correct?

I'm trying to follow html links with "/insertsomephrase/" in the address, which then follows a link with "/insertsomeotherphrase/" to be parsed. How does one do this in regex?

I'm confused as to how regex would do this since it seems the regex code acts on a string instead of an html element.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have any sample code for what you've tried thus far? Might be helpful to include that in your question so others can follow what you're trying to do.

Comment: Further to slm's comment, please also provide the actual URLs that are being parsed or suitable equivalents. :)